# Customise Contacts Relationships Tab

Tags: relationships, hooks, templates

I want to customise the contacts relationships tab screen to show if the listed contacts (Individuals) belong to a specific group or not. I'm not sure where to start and would appreciate any pointers. I wasn't sure whether I needed to customise a template or create an extension that uses a hook...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this through following ways:

1. Create [ACL rule](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Access+Control+Context+and+Overview) through UI to View Contact of specific group.
2. Create an extension and use pageRun hook to alter the $rows send to smarty template.
3. Create an extension and use aclWhereClause hook to restrict contacts to show.
4. Probably not sure apiWrappers or selectWhereClause might also be used.

Note: Using #1 and #3 will be affected on all pages/forms/reports.

HTH

Pradeep